# Serversocket has no function attribute send

Tags: python, sockets, server

`socket.accept` is returning a tuple

`server.socket()` is the correct usage

instead of `socket.close` `clientsocket.close()` is required to specify the socket defined above the `if` statement

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#host = '192.168.1.158'
host = socket.gethostbyname('192.168.1.158')
port = 444

serversocket.bind((host, port))
serversocket.listen(3)

while True:
    clientsocket = serversocket.accept
    address = serversocket.accept

    print("Received Connection From %s" % str(address))

    message = 'Hello! Thank you for connecting to the Server' + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(message.encode('ascii'))

    socket.close()
```

Error Message --->

Received Connection From <bound method socket.accept of <socket.socket fd=300, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.158', 444)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\WaffWaffles\Desktop\Server-TCP-Test\server.py", line 19, in 
clientsocket.send(message.encode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

I am using Visual Studios to Code in.

Comment: serversocket.accept is a function, you need parenthesis to call it. `serversocket.accept()`

Comment: Also, `socket.accept` returns a tuple.  You need `clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()`.  One line.

Comment: Also, you want `clientsocket.close()`, not `socket.close()`.

Comment: Thank you, i am following a tutorial on FreeCodeCamp.
It's very frustrating when the tutorials tell you too do the wrong thing.
Again, I appreciate your quick response.